# dynamically put condition in if block in Javascript

Tags: javascript

Is there a way by which we can dynamically put condition in "if" block according to user input?

like:-

```js
const filter
if (location === true) { // location is user input 
  filter = first condition
}
if (skill === true) { // skill is user input 
  filter = second condition
}
if (filter) {
  /* filter contains dynamic value if location is true then filter should contain first condition, if skill is 
  true filter should contain second condition and if both are two true then filter should contain both conditions*/

  console.log("Hello")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can evaluate the condition inside the `if` statement, then assign the result of the comparison to `filter`:

```js
const input = 'a';
var filter
if (input === 'a') {
  filter = 1 == true; //first condition
}else if (input === 'b') {
  filter = 0 == true; //second condition
}
if (filter) {
  console.log("Hello")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We need to rename location but perhaps you one or more of these?

```js
const filter = []
let loc = true;
let skill = false;
if (loc) filter.push("location") 
if (skill)  filter.push("skill") 
// show

if (filter.length) { // more than 0 items
  filter.forEach(item => console.log(item))
}
if (filter[0] === "skill") console.log("only skill")
else if (filter.length===1 && filter[0] === "location") console.log("only location")
else if (filter.length == 2) console.log("both")
```